# Effect of Low Vitamine B12 on Class 1 Medical

Tags: commercial-aviation, medical

Does anyone know what the effect of LOW Vitamin B12 is on an aviation medical class 1? My doctor did a blood test recently and put me on Vitamin B12 pills. Is this an issue for Aviation Medical doctors when they do a class 1 medical? i have to do mine shortly.

Comment: Is it impacting your health? Do you have a disease or condition?

Comment: No not really, i dont have any complaints

Comment: Which country are you asking about? The requirements for a class 1 medical can be different in different places.

Comment: @Pondlife FAA Medical

Comment: There are people with pacemakers who can get a 1st class medical.  You'll be fine if all you need is to take your vitamins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a doctor, really the best way to get definitive answers is by talking to an AME.

Vitamin B12 deficiency isn't by itself any sort of issue, lots of people get less than they need because of diet, especially vegetarians and vegans. Vitamin B12 deficiency can lead to a form of anemia, which is potentially disqualifying, unless it can be kept below a certain level.

So, if your doctor hasn't found any sort of anemia or other condition due to lack of B12 then there's no consideration on your medical. Work on getting more in your diet or keep up on the supplements. However, if you have anemia or some other condition due to the deficiency then it is a consideration on a medical.

Comment: Thanks for your help